# Exercise needed for a husky

Tags: exercise, husky

I always wanted to have a husky but I need to work during the day and they need much exercise so I'm not sure if I should get one.
I would be able to go for a walk or jogging in the morning and evening and play with the dog a little in between but when I'm at work he would have to be a long time alone at home.

I do have a garden where he could run or something but I don't know if that would be enough exercise or maybe I should pay someone to go for a walk with him during that time.

On the weekends I don't have to work so I would have a lot of time to exercise with him then.

What do you think should I rather not get a dog or is it fine?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend another breed. Please avoid dogs bred for high energy work like Huskies, Border Collies and other herding dogs and hounds. There are several (mostly smaller) breeds that don't need as much physical activity.

Just because your dog has a big garden doesn't mean that it will run laps or entertain itself.

I also recommend either adopting an adult dog or taking at least a week off when you get a puppy. Puppies need a lot of supervision and could develop bad behavior if left alone.

Answer (score 1):

A husky is a great dog, but they are a [Working Breed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_dog) (e.g. Huskies, German Shepherds, Border Collies, Spaniels etc), a dog bread specifically for a job or performing tasks and are normally high in energy and drive. Which is a huge commitment. Huskies where bread as sled and guard dogs. This remains in their genes to this day. Which is why they have high energy and require alot of exercise, if they had a choice they would be out for hours.

When they are puppies it is recommended that they are exercised for 5 minutes for every month of age, e.g. 1 month = 5 minutes, 6 months = 30 minutes and so on. This is because until around the age of 1 they rapidly grow and their bones are still soft due to growth. Until the age of 1 where they are almost fully grown.

Walking and jogging in the morning will be great (over the age of 1), this will tire them out for some of they day (most of it when they are younger), as they get older they will need more. So a walk or jog in the evening will be advantageous. I always aim for at-least 1 hour 30 minutes, an hour of highly intense activities minimum. I took my 2 year old German Shepherd out for a 5k Bike ride where she was constantly jogging at a quick pace and she still had energy for more!

Physical and mental activities and tasks combined will help, obedience work, tracking, running, chasing etc all are tiring.

Being home alone and being able to entertain themselves is something that needs to be trained in any dog. Being able to be comfortable in their own company is vital if you are out at work all day. I would recommend atleast 2-3 weeks off if you get a puppy to let it settle and start to teach it to be alone for long periods of time. Even then there is no guarantee it wont get bored and will need entertainment. Something like toys, bones, food that can last a day will keep it entertained.

Be warned puppies need **constant** supervision, even more so if they are working breeds and are borderline like having children. They see anything as a toy or something to chew so you need to be training it from a very young age, puppy classes are great too.

Big gardens are great but it doesnt mean dogs will utilise them, they have to be taught to and be entertained in them by you, working breeds especially. If working breeds are not entertained and exercised they become bored and destructive.

If this is off putting I would look at a different breed.